# Optimizing tweens

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, tween

What is the best way to clean up after tweens in AS3 no matter what library you are using (or the built-in tween classes). Is there a best-practice or is it specific to each tween library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's more specific to each library. TweenMax is pretty optimized on it's own and does a good job of cleaning up after itself. Check out the speed test comparisons - [link](http://www.greensock.com/tweening-speed-test/). If you have a lot of reoccurring tweens, using object pooling or reusing tween objects could help in optimization.

Comment: This is what I thought but I've been told to clean up after my tweens...for TweenMax I thought this meant using the kill() method but now I am just confused ;-(

Comment: About "reusing" do you mean create an instance and then call it repeatedly?

Comment: Exactly. Reusing that instance would likely optimize your application. For TweenMax, you can also use the OverwriteManager - [http://www.greensock.com/overwritemanager/](http://www.greensock.com/overwritemanager/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If with "clean up" you mean to clean up the memory used for animations in flash, try

```
System.gc();
```

to fire the garbage collection. It will sweep everything out what is not used or lost its reference.

Recycling is also a good idea, even though it highly depends on your coding style and actual project.

For more information on the garbage collection, see the [reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29).

Comment: It says system.gc only works for AIR, this is just a normal flash thing.

Comment: As far as I know, it does work for flash. I even use it. Check the (reference)[http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#gc()]. It says: "Runtime Versions :  AIR 1.0, Flash Player 9.0.115.0" This means, that in both AIR and the Player. Also, that from 9.0 concerning the player.